# How to skip a join based on a condition

Tags: postgresql

In my query I have a specific condition if user select "Jack" for example, I should skip a join in my query ,generally if the following count result is 0,i should skip the join :

Here is my condition:

```
 select count  (f.m_supervisor) from wpv.v_master f
 JOIN zd.t_users g on(g.user_id=f.pv_personid)
 where g.user_name Like('Jack')
```

the result of above join is 0,so I should skip the join in the following query

```
select sum(energy::numeric) Production,name, round(avg(mspeed), 2) speed, round(avg(m_cor), 2) avai
from wpv.v_daily v1
left outer join wh.t_ext t1 on t1.m_id = v1.m_id  and t1.m_date=v1.m_date
JOIN wpv.v_master f on (f.m_tid=v1.m_tid) 
JOIN zd.t_users g on(g.user_id=f.pv_personid)
where  (v1.m_date between '19/04/2018' and '20/04/2018')  AND g.user_name Like('%')
        and f.service Like('%')     
        and f.m_supervisor like ('%')----->This line should be skipped if count is 0                   
        group by 2
        order by 4 ASC
```

Comment: upvoted by three users sniffing for [postgresql] tag in 9 minutes? And I dont even understand the question :) do you want smth like `CASE WHEN THEN END` instead of `AND f.m_supervisor like ('%')`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I did my best to make it crear )))  sorry if its not,any way yes but how should I put this condition?

Comment: please create env on db-fiddle.com or give the sample data along with structure and demostrate the result you have and the result you wish - I cant imagine better explanation. sorry if I look picky, but you have several unrelated relations in your query I assume and first sql has twice as little of them as the second...

Comment: @VaoTsun I m trying to recreate it,but in the above query where I commented (This line should be skipped if count is 0)I want to put condition there

Comment: `AND g.user_name Like('%')
        and f.service Like('%')     
        and f.m_supervisor like ('%')` You should omit these, since they do nothing but turn your LEFT JOIN into a plain JOIN. (also: remove the parentheses)

Comment: @joop thanks for the answer but that's % because user selected All from the dropdown list,if user select name ('Jack')for the g.user_name then I want to omit or skip the f.m_supervisor like ('%')

Comment: So the `'%'` are actually expanded *empty* parameters ?

Comment: @joop I pass a variable  for each one,for example g.user_name like(" +user_name + @") and if(user_name='jack') then I should skip the f.m_supervisor